# AngularJS : Injecting string in directive from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any way to insert in a directive template an angular variable as a string? for example {{row.name}}, so that angular does not interpret it in the page only in the directive. something like this:

directive template:

```
<div>
   <div ng-transclude ng-repeat="row in data"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

A use case:
I send to the directive from the controller the data array.
person.name = "John", person.name = "Mike".
For this case my page would look like:

```
....
<div my-directive>
   Name: {{row.name}}
</div>
```

From another controller i send the data:
car.weight = 13, car.weight = 44
For this case my page would look like:

```
....
<div my-directive>
   Weight: {{row.weight}}
</div>
```

The result would be:
Name:
Name:
or
Weight:
Weight:

This is because {{row}} is undefined

Is this possible or am I understanding everything wrong and there's another way?

Comment: YES, you can use like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `row` property to transclusion scope. This is because the scope of `ng-transclude` directive does not inherit from `my-directive` scope, but from outer (page) scope.

One way to do it is to create special transclusion directive:

```
module.directive('myDirectiveTransclude', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
      $transclude(function(dom, transclusionScope) {
        transclusionScope.row = $scope.row;
        return elem.append(dom);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then replace `ng-transclude` with it:

```
<div>
    <div my-directive-transclude ng-repeat="row in data"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! just what i was looking for. Could you please explain step by step what myDirectiveTransclude does exactly?

Comment: @hhh3112 It will receive `$transclude` function which is responsible for rendering transcluded DOM provided by `my-directive` user (e.g. `Name: {{row.name}}`). Then it calls `$transclude` with single argument — a _clone linking function_, which in turn gets called with clone of transcluded DOM as first argument and  transclusion scope as second.

Comment: @hhh3112 The `$scope` inside `myDirectiveTransclude`'s link function is a child scope of `ng-repeat` scope (in fact, there will be as many calls to `link` as the number of items in `ng-repeat`), but it also prototypically inherits from it. The `transclusionScope` is also a child of `ng-repeat` scope, but it does not prototypically inherit from it; instead it inherits from outer scope — the one where your directive was placed.